# Is it natural to declare laterals and rhotics as a fortis/lenis pair?

Tags: conlang-creation, phonology, naturalism, chinese

I've sought for justification for the phoneme inventory of my conlang, but finally, I think I found one, at least for consonants.

|  | 순음 Labial | 설음 Coronal | 반설음 "Semi-coronal" | 치두음 Front Sibilant | 정치음 Rear Sibilant | 아음 Dorsal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Fortis** | P [p] | T [t] | **L [ɭ]** | C [t͜s] | Q [t͜ɕ] | K [kʰ] |
| **Lenis** | M [m] | N [n] | **R [ɻ~ɽ]** | Z [z] | J [ʑ] | G [k~k̚~g] |

This classification of consonants is due to the medieval phonologists of Chinese and Korean. And the orthography is quite consistent to the pinyin. The syllable structure is `(C)V(C)`, where the coda is lenis if present.

What I'm unsure about is the so-called "semi-coronal" consonants, as which Sejong The Great classified. Though Korean puts the lateral and the rhotic as the same phoneme, namely ㄹ, I decided to declare them as different phonemes because I wanted some "symmetric" structure for my conlang.

I think Sejong himself would've been convinced, but what about phonologists of medieval Chinese languages, or those of any other languages with strict fortis/lenis pairs?

Comment: Are you asking if it's phonologically natural—that is, if you'd expect a lateral in a leniting environment to turn into a rhotic, or a rhotic in a fortiting environment to turn into a lateral—or if it's natural for someone describing a language (especially in mediaeval times) to group them this way?

Comment: @Draconis The latter.